# mostrar un archivo .txt con fopen c++/c

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++, fopen

tengo una duda
Como puedo imprimir un archivo .txt con fopen, pero necesito que el nombre sea pedido de teclado.
tengo esto pero no me funciona, no muestra nada de lo que contiene el archivo como deberia:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    
    char *pep;
    cout<<"ingrsa el nombre de tu archivo .txt con la extencion"<<endl;
    cout<<"ejemplo (HOLAMUNDO.txt)"<<endl;
    cin>>pep;
    char *modo="r";
    FILE *archivo =fopen(pep,modo);
    int c;
    while((c=fgetc(archivo))!= EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Primero, C++ y C son lenguajes diferentes.

Aunque C++ está basado en C, este tiene su modo de hacer las cosas.

---

Un error es que no estás indicando el tipo de retorno de la función `main`. Este debe ser `int`.

El otro es que `cin >> pep` intenta escribir a la dirección de memoria en `pep`. Pero este no está inicializado, tiene basura. Por lo que escribirá a una dirección que no le pertenece, normalmente generando un error.

Lo más simple es que uses un arreglo con la suficiente capacidad en su lugar, por ejemplo 20 caracteres:

```
char pep[20];
```

También es recomendable que en este caso uses [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) ya que te permite pedir un máximo de caracteres. Mientras que el operador **<<** de `cin` puede generar errores el tamaño de la entrada excede el del buffer.

```
cin.getline(pep, 20);
```

También podrías usar memoria del heap en lugar de un arreglo. Pero me parece que no vale la pena para este caso.

---

Ya que estás en C++, sugiero que uses funciones de STL, entre ellas [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [`fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) y [`iostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream).

También, si necesitas funcionalidad de C, es preferible que uses las cabeceras llamadas `cx` en lugar de `x.h`. Por ejemplo: `stdlib.h` -> `cstdlib`, `string.h` -> `cstring`, `stdio.h` -> `cstdio`.

El código quedaría así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{

    string pep;
    cout << "Ingresa el nombre de tu archivo .txt con la extension" << endl;
    cout << "ejemplo (HOLAMUNDO.txt)" << endl;
    cin >> pep;

    fstream archivo(pep, ios::in);
    if (!archivo) {
        cout << "No se pudo abrir\n";
        return;
    }

    int c = archivo.get();
    while(!archivo.eof())
    {
        cout << (char)c;
        cout << archivo.get();
    }

    cout << "\n";
    archivo.close();
    system("pause");
}
```

Nota que con `string` te olvidas de lidiar con varios problemas. Entre ellos, un tamaño limitado.