# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un valor a un arreglo bidimensional, pero sin meter el arreglo directo al gets?

Tags: array, c

Me dice que no puedo asignar el valor, ya que quiero que primero el valor pase por la variable pal para así poder utilizarla después.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char nombres[3][30];
    int i;
    char *pal;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("Cual es tu nombre:");
        gets(pal);
        nombres[i]=&pal;
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%s\n",nombres[i]);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pal` no apunta a ninguna parte. Tienes un problema similar a otro que respondí hace poco https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/541199/169744 sé que tu pregunta es sobre C, pero igual te puede servir.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí estás declarando un puntero:

```
char *pal;
```

Un puntero no es más que una variable que almacena direcciones de memoria. ¿Qué dirección de memoria está almacenando este puntero? Pues dado que no lo has inicializado ninguna o, mejor dicho, una aleatoria.

A continuación intentas escribir en la región de memoria direccionada por el puntero

```
gets(pal);
```

Pero como hemos dicho antes, esta dirección es aleatoria, luego es bastante probable que esa región de memoria no pertenezca a tu aplicación. Lo que sucede entonces es que el Sistema Operativo detecta el acceso a memoria que no te pertenece y, por seguridad, mata tu proceso (realmente esto es lo mejor que podría pasarte)

Así que para poder guardar algo en `pal`, necesitamos que apunte a una dirección de memoria válida para nuestro propósito:

```
char * pal = (char*)malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
```

Claro que, para este caso, nos valdría también con declarar un array:

```
char pal[30];
```

Con esto estaría solucionado el primer error, vamos a por el segundo:

```
nombres[i]=&pal;
```

Esta operación no tiene sentido lo mires como lo mires.

Dado que `pal` es un puntero, `&pal` te devolverá la dirección de memoria del puntero. Este valor solo se puede almacenar en un puntero doble. `nombres[i]` es un array ... son tipos incompatibles.

Para copiar el puntero necesitarías declarar `nombres` tal que `char* nombres[3]`, pero entonces tendrías un problema y es que tras la ejecución del bucle, las 3 posiciones apuntarían al mismo sitio ... el puntero `pal`.

Lo que tu pretendes es leer 3 cadenas de texto y almacenarlas en `nombres`. Esto lo puedes hacer simplificando tu código:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("Cual es tu nombre:");
    gets(nombres[i]);
}
```

También lo puedes hacer usando un buffer intermedio. No se por qué querrías hacerlo así, pero se puede. Lo único que para copiar cadenas de un sitio a otro debes usar una función, como `strcpy`, no puedes hacerlo con el operador de asignación:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("Cual es tu nombre:");
    gets(pal);
    strcpy(nombres[i], pal);
}
```

Como corolario, podrías evitar las copias, pero para ello vas a tener que reservar manualmente memoria para cada cadena:

```
char* nombres[3];

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("Cual es tu nombre:");
    char* pal = (char*)malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
    gets(pal);
    nombres[i] = pal;
}
```

Lo que se hace ahora es almacenar en cada posición de `nombres`, la dirección de memoria que hemos reservado en cada iteración. Así, cada nombre se almacenará en una posición de memoria diferente